# function calls are not supported in decorators but 'makeDecorator' was called in 'NgModule' while using SwipeCardsModules in Ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using Tinder cars and for this I am using SwipeCardsModule but it is giving me the following error.
I have referenced everything from this link https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/ionic-framework-3/ionic-3-tinder-like-cards
The error is shown below

```
  Error during template compile of 'SwipeCardsModule' Function 
     calls 
   are not supported in decorators but 'makeDecorator' was called in 
  'NgModule' 'NgModule' references 'NgModule' 'NgModule' references 
  'NgModule''NgModule' references 'NgModule' calls 'makeDecorator'.

 Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
at /home/benepik/Desktop/currently working/kriti/bestieionic2new/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:237:55
at step (/home/benepik/Desktop/currently working/kriti/bestieionic2new/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:32:23)
at Object.next (/home/benepik/Desktop/currently working/kriti/bestieionic2new/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:13:53)
at fulfilled (/home/benepik/Desktop/currently working/kriti/bestieionic2new/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:4:58)
```

Please help

Comment: Did you find a solution ?